# Battery Draining for Forerunner music 645

Tags: garmin

My forerunner's battery will drain big time if i pair it with cadence and speed sensor, anybody encounter same problem with me? Any suggested solution?

Comment: How old is the battery?  I get 18 months of daily use off a gopro battery before it can't handle the whole commute.   Does the battery last longer if you disable the sensors?    Are the sensors connected by Bluetooth or ANT?   If bluetooth, which version are your sensors offering ?

Comment: Numbers would be good: runtime from full/freshly charged to empty, with and without sensors enabled

Comment: I don't know how the Garmin sensors work, but my normal (magnet-based) wireless sensors seem to drain the head unit battery faster if the _sensor_ batteries are low, for what reason I don't understand.  Could something like that be happening to you?